# how to handle the 404 response when youtube_it gem doesn't find a video

Tags: ruby, youtube, rubygems, http-status-code-404, open-uri

I'm using the gem youtube_it in a Sinatra app. I would like to use it to check if a youtube video id is valid.

```
client.video_by(youtube_id)
```

is the query.  I get this response when the id is invalid.

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 400
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/youtube_it-2.1.4/lib/youtube_it/parser.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/youtube_it-2.1.4/lib/youtube_it/client.rb:95:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/youtube_it-2.1.4/lib/youtube_it/client.rb:95:in `video_by'
    from (irb):22
```

I'm not sure how to handle this so I can tell my user that the id they provided is invalid.

Thanks!

P.S. I really do answer questions, I've just been asking some pretty tough questions lately and haven't been getting responses. This one shouldn't be too tough for you guys though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you catch the error like this, but you can give it a try.

```
begin  
  .... 
  client.video_by(youtube_id)
  ... 
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
  flash[:notice] = "Oh no! Something bad happened..."
  redirect_to(:action => 'search')
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I haven't gotten the flash message part operational, but I guess that's a new question.  :)